# How to change the reference style to apa, using ampersand ("&") instead of "and" in in-text citations?

Tags: apa-style, cleanthesis

I am using the cleanthesis template and want to use apa citation style, which lists two authors with an ampersand (&).
I managed to change the the format in the reference list by changing the 'style' in the cleanthesis.sty:

```
    %backend=\cthesis@bibsys,       %   - use biber backend (bibtex replacement) or bibtex
    bibencoding=utf8,               %   - use auto file encode
    style=apa,                      %   - use alphabetic (or numeric) bib style
    %style=\cthesis@bibstyle,       %   - use alphabetic (or numeric) bib style
    natbib=true,                    %   - allow natbib commands
    hyperref=true,                  %   - activate hyperref support
    backref=false,                  %   - activate backrefs
    isbn=false,                     %   - don't show isbn tags
    url=false,                      %   - don't show url tags
    doi=false,                      %   - don't show doi tags
    urldate=long,                   %   - display type for dates
    maxnames=3,%
    minnames=1,%
    maxbibnames=5,%
    minbibnames=3,%
    maxcitenames=2,%
    mincitenames=1%
]{biblatex}
```

Which leads to the result I am looking for in my bibliography:

Rosenfeld, A., & Richardson, A. (2019). Explainability in human–agent systems. *Autonomous
Agents and Multi-Agent Systems*, 33(6), 673–705.

But, in the body of my work the citation looks like this:
Rosenfeld and Richardson, 2019

How can I convert it to
Rosenfeld & Richardson, 2019 ?

Comment: Looking at the documentation, it seems that `\parencite` does use an ampersand.

Answer (score 1):

If you want proper APA style, you should probably get rid of most `biblatex` options and load the package only with

```
 \usepackage[backend=biber, style=apa]{biblatex}
```

(or with `\RequirePackage` instead of `\usepackage` if the package is loaded from a `.sty` file).

You can then use one of the commands `\autocite` (which with the standard settings of `biblatex-apa` behaves like `\parencite` - you can change that with the `autocite` package option), `\parencite` (for "parenthetical citations"), `\textcite` (for "narrative citations") or `\nptextcite` (for "parenthetical citations" that are already inside parentheses).

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=apa]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson}

ipsum \parencite{sigfridsson}

dolor \textcite{sigfridsson}

sit \nptextcite{sigfridsson}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Lorem (Sigfridsson & Ryde, 1998) ipsum (Sigfridsson & Ryde, 1998) dolor Sigfridsson and Ryde (1998) sit Sigfridsson & Ryde, 1998]